# What is the extension for Haskell?

Tags: haskell

What extension should I use for a Haskell file?

Comment: Can you write more clearly? What do you mean by 'Haskell script'. Like a scripting language?

Comment: Try '*.hs*'. For further research, good you do that, try http://learnyouahaskell.com/.

Comment: I am glad to read that you seem to be interested in Haskell, however please do some basic research on your own https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)

Comment: Are you looking for a shebang pattern? `#!/usr/[local/]bin/runhaskell` for example?

Comment: It is all right to have it here, but there should be only one. Can we declare this one the canonical question? Even if it was late, 2016, I couldn't find any duplicates, but perhaps they do exist. I tried to use "`site:stackoverflow.com "file extension" haskell`" to make the search more specific.

Comment: File extensions are not significant on all operating systems - it is mostly Windows that cares about how a file is named, most other OSs don't care.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's mostly programs that care about file extensions, not operating systems. In particular **GHC** cares about extensions; try putting `main = putStrLn "hello"` in a file named `foo.c` and then running `ghc foo.hs`. Then try no extension, or a random long made up one. You actually do need to put your Haskell source in `.hs` files (or `.lhs`, but that's a different format so the same file won't work for both; the compiler uses the extension to decide which format it should try to process).

Answer (score 33):

Two common extensions are `.hs` and `.lhs`. The difference is in how the compiler handles comments. In a `.hs` file, comments begin with `--` or are enclosed in `{-`/`-}` pairs.

```
{- This is a multiline comment
   about my factorial function
 -}

-- It's simple using builtins
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

In a `.lhs` file, every line is considered a comment, unless it is explicitly marked as code. There are two different styles you can use,
although you must use only one within a single file. First, you can mark
lines of code by prefix them with `>`:

```
In this file, we will implement factorial.

> factorial :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a
> factorial n = product [1..n]
```

To embed code in a file that can be processed by LaTeX to produce
nice looking documentation, code can instead appear in a `code` block:

```
In this file, we will implement factorial.

\begin{code}
factorial :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a
factorial n = product [1..n]
\end{code}
```

Both are equivalent to the following `.hs` file:

```
-- In this file, we will implement factorial
factorial :: (Enum a, Num a) => a -> a
factorial n = product [1..n]
```