# Received warning: ignoring unrecognized input when I tried to open file .sh script

Tags: haskell

I'm studying a course in my university that is using Haskell. As instructed, I installed GHC 7.6.1 (for Window x86) and tried some examples on GHCi. Everything went smoothly until I write some script on Notepad (test.sh) and tried to open it, I received this:

```
GHCi, version 7.6.1 http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Warning: ignoring unrecognised input 'C:\Users\longx\OneDrive\Desktop\LTNC\test.sh'
Prelude>
```

Does anyone know how can I fix this? Btw here are the contents of `test.sh`:

```
double x = x + x

quadruple x = double (double x)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). You need to spend a few minutes taking the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) The file extension should not be `sh`, but `hs`. See: [What is the extension for Haskell file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746472/what-is-the-extension-for-haskell). How do you run the ghci command?

Comment: @David Lukas Thank you so much! I've spent hours trying to figure it out not knowing that I got the file extension wrong. Silly me. It works fine now. 
"How do you run the ghci command?" I run the ghci from the Start menu and double click the source file.